# .NET MVC - Url.Action not working for specific action/controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

If I do for example this on a view:

```
  @Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")
```

it prints:

```
   /Account/LogOff
```

as expected.

The same with any other controller and action I have tested, or in fact for any pair of strings I put there, except for Account/Login:

```
  @Url.Action("Login", "Account")
```

prints

```
  /
```

I dont get it. anything I put there works and prints the expected string, except for (apparently) Account/Login. 
why?

Comment: is that set as your default route, perhaps?

Comment: have you mentioned any `action name` in controller like `[ActionName("AccountLogin")]` ?? can you post controller action please